# How to get Googlenews links for a custom query entered

Tags: web-scraping, nlp, python-3.6, sentiment-analysis, google-news

I want to write a code in Python 3 that would search Google News with a different query every time.
All the resulting links are to be stored in a list and I plan to scrape those links further for sentiment analysis.
I am using the following GoogleNews package and the following code to get the links, but I am not getting any result. I am getting an empty list.

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
googlenews = GoogleNews()
googlenews.search('AAPL')
googlenews.getlinks()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzvuN.png)

Comment: What is the result of googlenews.result() & googlenews.gettext() after googlenews.search('AAPL')?

Comment: an empty list comes up.

Comment: werid.... I just tried on python3.6 and it gave me the list correctly.... Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, I am behind a proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately, this package does not have support for proxy per https://github.com/HurinHu/GoogleNews/blob/master/build/lib/GoogleNews/googlenews.py. You will need to copy its source to add proxy support via soup. https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping-cheat-sheet/#using-proxy-servers